# How to modify request bodies by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've tried use chrome.webRequest API and finally found out that it looks like google don't allow us to modify requestBodies of POST requests? I could only cancel it or modify its headers.
So is there any other way to modify the raw (not form) body of a post request? I know that a proxy server could do that but I want to deal with it using extension.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome extension [Netify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netify/mdafhjaillpdogjdigdkmnoddeoegblj) allows request modification, including POST body

Comment: I've had a quick look through their GitHub but can't see how they do it. Do you know which APIs they're using?

Comment: @Aron No I'm just user, not author

Answer (score 2):

This works for some cases: first, save the body of the request in a variable in the `onBeforeRequest` listener. Then, in `onBeforeSendHeaders` you can either cancel or redirect the original request (sorry, Chrome gives you only two options to deal with the original). Also in `onBeforeSendHeaders`, you issue a new request (say, jquery ajax) to which you attach the old body from the variable, and the old headers - both can be modified/rewritten as needed. 
(Minor catch: it won't let you set all of the headers for "security reasons", so you may add one more `onBeforeSendHeaders` listener to add the sensitive headers to the new request as well).

Works for cases when the request issuer is happy with a redirect or cancel as a response. If the request issuer expects the full actual response, intact, with no redirects, then it gets harder.